# get new array with specific values changed to .map() in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I would like to get a new array with changed data using the .map() method

```js
const arr = [
    { idx: 0, val: "a" },
    { idx: 1, val: "b" }
];
console.log(arr); // output: [ { idx: 0, val: 'a' }, { idx: 1, val: 'b' } ]

const map1 = arr.map((e) => e.val === "a" ? e.val = "c" : e);
console.log(map1); // output: [ 'c', { idx: 1, val: 'b' } ]

// but i want: [ { idx: 0, val: 'c' }, { idx: 1, val: 'b' } ]
```

What I've tried is below.
But I'd like to know if it's possible with a map().

```js
var arr2 = arr;

const idx = arr2.findIndex(e => e.val === "a");
arr2[idx].val = "c";

console.log(arr2); // output: [ { idx: 0, val: 'c' }, { idx: 1, val: 'b' } ]
setState(arr2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
arr.map((e) => e.val === 'a' ? { ...e, val: 'c' } : e)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes but you always need to return a full object. And you should not mutate the object within the map.

```
const map1 = arr.map((e) => ({...e, val: e.val === "a" ? 'c' : e.val}));
```

Comment: It is possible to mutate the source array in `.map()`, but it's not a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yu need to return an object with new value for keys

```js
const arr = [{
    idx: 0,
    val: "a"
  },
  {
    idx: 1,
    val: "b"
  }
];

const map1 = arr.map((e) => {
  return {
    idx: e.idx,
    val: e.val === "a" ? "c" : e.val
  }

})
console.log(map1);
```